# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" when saving to another drive in Python script executed in SSH session

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

On the server machine:

```
print("Python Script")
filename = 'C:\\..\\store.txt'
file = open(filename, 'w')
file.write('text')
file.close()
```

Produces a file called store.txt when ran on the server machine; it works as expected. It behaves correctly also when executed over SSH with the following script:

```
host   = '...'
user   = '...'
passwd = '...'
ssh    = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port=22, username=user, password=passwd, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

command = "C:\\path_to_script\\script.py"
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(command)

for line in stdout:
    print(line)

for line in stderr:
    print(line)
```

When writing in a different drive `O:\\...`, from the server this also works as expected.

Finally, when executing the python script via SSH (using paramiko), I get the error from the title:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'O:\...
```

The file is not being 'Opened' to begin with, let alone writing. I'm on a Windows machine, any advice on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that it's a mapped network drive.

The drive most likely does not get mapped in the SSH session.

Try using an UNC path instead.